# Save slider value and load it?

Tags: unity

I'm trying to save a slider value and load it when I run again the game. but here is not working. yes, I can change the value and save it but not load it.

```
    public Slider Brightness;
    public float bri,briv; // only briv value I saving it. 

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("briv");
        Brightness.value = briv;
        }

    void Update() {
            briv = bri;
            bri = Brightness.value; 

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S)) {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("briv",briv);
        Debug.Log ("save");
    }

        } // end update
```

Comment: Why have `bri` at all? You should also use better variable names. When you get back to your code later you will be happy you did.

Comment: @simbabque im agree , but its up to him tho , also you can instantly change all variable name using the search and replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not setting the return value of the function, try this `briv = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("briv");` instead of `PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("briv");` and it should work as you want it to.